# How can I extend JQuery ajaxSetup settings?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add some additional properties to the `Settings` for `ajaxSetup`.

I will then access these settings from `BeforeSend` and `OnComplete` callbacks of `Ajax`.

For example is should look something like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  myCustomProperty: 'SomeValue'
});
```

Then:

```
   $.ajax({
          type : 'POST',
          url : url,
          async : false,
          data : postData,
          beforeSend : function (x, settings){
               alert(settings.myCustomProperty);
          },
          complete : function () {
               alert(settings.myCustomProperty);
          }
   });
```

I'm not sure how to access the interals of `ajaxSetup` to extend `Settings`?

Comment: Are you trying to refer to [$.ajaxSetup](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/)?

Comment: @probackpacker ah sorry, updated typo in my question. Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to customize the jQuery $.ajax() call, I wouldn't do it through $.ajaxSetup(). jQuery specifically recommends against using $.ajaxSetup in the first place. From the [API docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/):

> Description: Set default values for future Ajax requests. Its use is
>   not recommended.

I would recommend instead creating your own method that calls $.ajax() internally:

```
function myAwesomeAjax(settingsObj){
    // do some awesome stuff with your custom properties here
    var myCustomProperty = "jQuery is awesome!";

    return $.ajax(settingsObj);
}
```

In general, the guys at jQuery know what they're doing and you shouldn't try to muck with it too much.

If all you're trying to do is create a variable that you can access in callbacks, just give it global scope. For bonus points, hide all your stuff in a global "namespace" to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Ah, sorry I had it the wrong way around you are correct, I wanted to pass a value from the .ajax call for use in a common beforesend.

Answer (score -1):

You can set default parameters for ajax in this way:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: {
        myCustomProperty: 'SomeValue'
    }
});
```

Comment: that only applies to the default settings this would be an extension to those.